# How can I pass a variable from a each do to a form_for inside it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, each, form-for

I have a `<% @user.comments.each do |comment| %>`

and inside it is

`<%= form_for [????, Subcomment.new],:remote => true do |form| %>`

What can I use at ???? to ensure that the current `@user.comment` is passed to the controller?

If I use

`<%= form_for [comment, Subcomment.new],:remote => true do |form| %>`

I get

```
No route matches {:controller=>"subcomments", :comment_id=>#<Comment body: "Comments coming up twice", user_id: 2, commenter: "gleb", id: nil>}
```

Comment: show your routes for subcomment resources

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you need to create a hidden field `comment_id`